# Slack API how to get conversations.list for different workspaces that installed the app?

Tags: django, slack, slack-api

Using [this app as an example](https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-python/tree/e6079cdc8865f28eb06500a3ed2c82de104b55bc/examples/django), how could I call `conversations_list` method while differentiating the conversations list I want for different workspaces? Do I have to construct a different `WebClient` with some specific `token`? If so, how do I store OAuth tokens generated for each workspace (as in I don't think the code example linked above handles storing OAuth tokens)?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: The code example does store installed tokens. Check : https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-python/tree/e6079cdc8865f28eb06500a3ed2c82de104b55bc/examples/django#oauth_app---multiple-workspace-app-example-oauth-flow-supported and https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-python/blob/e6079cdc8865f28eb06500a3ed2c82de104b55bc/examples/django/oauth_app/slack_datastores.py

Comment: You can use token from each workspace to get associated  conversation lists.

Comment: Ok I just realized that the `bot_token` for each workspace would be different (but remain the same within each workspace for all installations). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the sample code provided in the question:

```py
class SlackInstallation(models.Model):
    client_id = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=32)
    app_id = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=32)
    ... ...
    team_id = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=32)
    team_name = models.TextField(null=True)
    bot_token = models.TextField(null=True)  # <= access_token returned by /api/oauth.v2.access
    bot_id = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=32)
    ... ...
```

The `bot_token` is unique for each workspace. So this is actually the token to be updated for the `app.client` or `Webclient(token=bot_token)` before one could ping API for the correct workspace.